# Order of execution for class in javascript

Tags: javascript, class, console.log

```
class Department{   
 constructor(){     
  console.log('parent class')   
 } 
} 
class Employee extends Department{  
  constructor(){    
   super()     
   console.log('child constructor method')   
  }     
  findName(){       
   console.log('Vimal');   
  } 
} 
let E1 = new Employee(); console.log(E1.findName())
```

Now in the above code it gives me the logs as "parent class" "child constructor method" "User Name" undefined Now where is this undefined coming from can anyone help me understand this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function,

```js
findName(){       
   console.log('Vimal');   
  }
```

Returns `undefined` (by default in JavaScript, function that does not explicitly return something - return `undefined`).

So when you do `console.log(E1.findName())`, you do 2 things:

1. Run the function, then `Vidal` will be logged
2. Printing the return value of `E1.findName()`. The function returns `undefined` so indeed `undefined` is logged.